# Android MPC app to quickly create a beat

Tags: android, audio, music-production

Are there any Android apps comparable to **Akai's [iMPC](https://itunes.apple.com/app/impc/id584548447)**, which is sadly only available for iOS?

Searching in PlayStore for *"MPC"* only results in cheaply made apps with fixed loops on the buttons.

I know about [FL Studio Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imageline.FLM) and [Groove Machine Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imageline.GrooveMachineMobile), but those are kind of an overkill and the later seems to not be optimized for smartphones (or I just downloaded the wrong APK, the one for tablets...).

**What I'd like to do:**

- Create different sequences from a preinstalled loop-selection.
- Browse my own files to sample songs
- Assemble sequences to a beat

It doesn't have to be free. I like to pay for good software.